# Binance API with Google Script

Tags: javascript, google-sheets, urlfetch

I am attempting to pull my trade history from Binance (using signed endpoint security) into google sheets so that I can keep records of all my trades using google scripts.  I am stuck where I can't pull the data using the api keys.  The below snippit is as far as I could get from my understaning of the Binance API and UrlFetchApp API.

> var data = UrlFetchApp.fetch("https://api.binance.com/api/v3/myTrades", {headers : apiKey})

I also have found [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47984654/binance-api-keys).

[Binance API Website](https://www.binance.com/restapipub.html#user-content-signed-endpoint-security)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't add the header in the url bar.

EDIT I see you are using UrlFetchApp. In that case, the correct syntax is

```
var headers = {'X-MBX-APIKEY': apiKey}
UrlFetchApp.fetch("https://api.binance.com/api/v3/myTrades", {'headers': headers})
```

Comment: I am using google scripts and as far as I know, `XMLHttpRequest` isnt supported

Comment: That has helped, I now get an error on the signature parameter, could you also explain that portion of the api?

Comment: Sure, if you approve my answer and ask another question and I'll take a look.

Comment: This is potentially also useful as its a link to a full Binance API script on a tech forum which you can download and use instead: https://stadivm.com/threads/how-to-get-all-historic-data-from-binances-api-using-this-script-and-build-macd-rsi-etc.153/