# Binance API Signature with Google Scripts

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, urlfetch

I am stuck on how to correctlly include the signitue into my get command based off of the [Binance API](https://www.binance.com/restapipub.html) within Google Scripts. What it states is

> SIGNED endpoints require an additional parameter, signature, to be sent in the query string or request body.
>   Endpoints use HMAC SHA256 signatures. The HMAC SHA256 signature is a keyed HMAC SHA256 operation. Use your secretKey as the key and totalParams as the value for the HMAC operation.
>   The signature is not case sensitive.
>   totalParams is defined as the query string concatenated with the request body.

What I have is:

```
function BinanceTrades() {
  var curTime = Number(new Date().getTime()).toFixed(0)
  var sKey = Utilities.computeHmacSha256Signature('symbol=LTCBTC&timestamp=' + curTime, '**mySeceretKey**');
  Logger.log(sKey)
  var headers = {'X-MBX-APIKEY': '**myKey**'}
  var data = UrlFetchApp.fetch("https://api.binance.com/api/v3/allOrders?signature=" + sKey + "&symbol=LTCBTC&timestamp=" + curTime, {'headers' : headers})
  Logger.log(data)
}
```

and the error I get is:

> {"code":-1100,"msg":"Illegal characters found in parameter 'signature'; legal range is '^[A-Fa-f0-9]{64}$'."}

I am unsure of how to compute the HMAC SHA256 correctly and incorporate the totalParams.

My previous post was [this.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48178861/binance-api-with-google-script)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

How about these modifications?

### Modification points :

From [the manual you provided](https://www.binance.com/restapipub.html)

- In your case, the string which is used for the signature is `"symbol=LTCBTC&timestamp=" + curTime`.
- The signature is the string of the unsigned hexadecimal.

  - But at Google Apps Script, the data which was encrypted by `Utilities.computeHmacSha256Signature()` is the bytes array of the signed hexadecimal.

The modified script which reflected above points is as follows.

### Modified script :

```
function BinanceTrades() {
  var key = '**myKey**';
  var secret = '**mySeceretKey**';

  var curTime = Number(new Date().getTime()).toFixed(0);
  var string = "symbol=LTCBTC&timestamp=" + curTime;
  var sKey = Utilities.computeHmacSha256Signature(string, secret);
  sKey = sKey.map(function(e) {
      var v = (e < 0 ? e + 256 : e).toString(16);
      return v.length == 1 ? "0" + v : v;
  }).join("");
  var params = {
    'method': 'get',
    'headers': {'X-MBX-APIKEY': key},
    'muteHttpExceptions': true
  };
  var url = "https://api.binance.com/api/v3/allOrders?" + string + "&signature=" + sKey;
  var data = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, params);
  Logger.log(data.getContentText())
}
```

### Note :

- About the encryption of signature, it has already confirmed that this script works fine from [the manual you provided](https://www.binance.com/restapipub.html).
- I have no account for binance.com. So I couldn't run this script. I'm sorry.

  - When you run this script, if the error occurs, can you show me the error messages?

Comment: Thank you, This runs and looks to pull the data that I needed.

Comment: @Kayracer Welcome. I could study from your question. Thank you, too.

Comment: Thank you for this, really, saved me a lot of time and trouble someone having already figured this out.

Comment: @Mark Kramer I'm glad your issue was solved. Thank you for your comment!