# Cryptocurrency Exchange API JSON live data to google spreadsheet

Tags: json, api, exchange-server, spreadsheet, cryptocurrency

I'm tryig to get JSON data from cryptocurrency exchange API to google spreadsheet.

I wrote a script for Poloniex and Cex.io or many exchanges, but I have an error for Binance. can you please help me to find what is the problem and what is the correction?

here is my working codes for Poloniex and others.

```js
function ttt() {

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById('1J15kMAiE1alyBhqP5VB3C8-_8C6m60PkT0e5nUsWpBE');



var Polo = ss.getSheetByName("Polo");
  ss.setActiveSheet(Polo);
Polo.getRange('A1:E1000').clearContent();

var url= "https://poloniex.com/public?command=returnOrderBook&currencyPair=BTC_ARDR&depth=1";
var responseAPI = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url);
var parcedData = JSON.parse(responseAPI.getContentText());
var asks = [];
asks.push(['askRate', 'askAmount']);
for(var key in parcedData.asks)
{asks.push(parcedData.asks[key]);}
Polo.getRange(1, 2, asks.length, 2).setValues(asks);



var url= "https://api.aex.com/ticker.php?c=all&mk_type=btc";
var responseAPI = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url);
var parcedData = JSON.parse(responseAPI.getContentText());
    var buy = [[parcedData.ardr.ticker.buy]];
  aex.getRange(2, 2, 1, 1).setValue(buy);
   var sell = [[parcedData.ardr.ticker.sell]];
  aex.getRange(2, 3, 1, 1).setValue(sell);
```

BUT!!! the binance API doesnt work why?

https://api.binance.com/api/v3/ticker/bookTicker

Comment: Will this be useful for you? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48191838/binance-api-signature-with-google-scripts/48197317#48197317