# {msg=Signature for this request is not valid., success=false} error for Binance Api withdraw and deposit request

Tags: javascript, api, google-apps-script, signature, binance

following [this answer on stack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48191838/binance-api-signature-with-google-scripts) I was able to correctly fetch all orders or trades data from my personal binance account.

```js
function connect() {

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheets()[0];

  var key = '****';
  var secret = '****';

  var curTime = Number(new Date().getTime()).toFixed(0);
  var symbol = "TRXETH";
  var limit  = 13;
  var string = "symbol="+symbol+"&limit=12&timestamp=" + curTime;
  var sKey = Utilities.computeHmacSha256Signature(string, secret);
  sKey = sKey.map(function(e) {
      var v = (e < 0 ? e + 256 : e).toString(16);
      return v.length == 1 ? "0" + v : v;
  }).join("");
  var params = {
    'method': 'get',
    'headers': {'X-MBX-APIKEY': key},
    'muteHttpExceptions': true
  };
  var url = "https://api.binance.com/api/v3/myTrades?" + string + "&signature=" + sKey;
  var data = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, params);
  var data = JSON.parse(data.getContentText());
```

It works just fine but, since I needed to pull *also deposit and withdraw data*, I thought I'd made a new dedicated script.
 And **it does not work**:

```js
function deposit() {

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheets()[0];

  var key = '****';
  var secret = '****';

  var curTime = Number(new Date().getTime()).toFixed(0);
  var string = "/wapi/v3/withdrawHistory.html?timestamp=" + curTime;
  var sKey = Utilities.computeHmacSha256Signature(string, secret);
  sKey = sKey.map(function(e) {
      var v = (e < 0 ? e + 256 : e).toString(16);
      return v.length == 1 ? "0" + v : v;
  }).join("");
  var params = {
    'method': 'get',
    'headers': {'X-MBX-APIKEY': key},
    'muteHttpExceptions': true,
    //'signature': sKey
  };
  var url = "https://api.binance.com" + string + "&signature=" + sKey;
  var data = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, params);
  var data = JSON.parse(data.getContentText());
```

now there are several tickets on github for this problem, but none seems to fit my case: can anyone tell me what is wrong with my code? thanks

[Github 1](https://github.com/jaggedsoft/php-binance-api/issues/230)
[Github 2](https://github.com/jaggedsoft/php-binance-api/pull/248) [Binance Official Documentation](https://github.com/binance-exchange/binance-official-api-docs/blob/master/wapi-api.md)

Comment: Can you explain the detail information of about `it does not work`? By the way, I think that in your script, the endpoint is not correct. So can I ask you what method of Binance API you want to use?

Comment: it means that when I try to connect with the first function it retrieves correctly all the data; whit the second one (deposit()) it gives the error reported in title, i.e.: "{msg=Signature for this request is not valid., success=false}". I need to use GET if that's what you mean. I hope I understood correctly, otherwise feel free to ask even in more detail if needed. thanks

Comment: Thank you for replying. From your replying, it is found that your tokens for accessing to Binance API is correct. And from your script, I noticed that you want to use the method of Withdraw History in Binance API. In this case, how about the following modification? Unfortunately, I cannot test the modified script. So if that didn't resolve your issue, please show the error message. I would like to check the script again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Your tokens for accessing to Binance API is correct.
- You want to use the method of Withdraw History in Binance API.

I could understand like above from your script and replying. If my understanding is correct, how about the following modification?

#### Modified script:

From:

```
var string = "/wapi/v3/withdrawHistory.html?timestamp=" + curTime;
```

To:

```
var string = "timestamp=" + curTime;
```

and

From:

```
var url = "https://api.binance.com" + string + "&signature=" + sKey;
```

To:

```
var url = "https://api.binance.com/wapi/v3/withdrawHistory.html?" + string + "&signature=" + sKey;
```

#### Reference:

- [Withdraw History of Binance API](https://github.com/binance-exchange/binance-official-api-docs/blob/master/wapi-api.md#withdraw-history-user_data)

Comment: thanks it works! Can I ask you what's the reason behind this change? I also have been reading the page you referenced but didn't understand how you got to that solution. ps, what about ```'contentType':'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'```: it works both with or without, what does that imply if it doesnt take too long to explain? thanks

Comment: @John Galassi Thank you for replying and testing it. I'm glad your issue was resolved. The default content type is `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` for UrlFetchApp. [Ref](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/url-fetch/url-fetch-app#fetchurl,-params) So it works for both with and without. And from your question, I could know that your above script works. So I could modify your below script like that.